# How can I get cookies from Express API to React?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, react-redux, mern

I am working on Login System. In the frontend, when I click the Login Button, a function runs which makes an API call using axios. Here is the function

```js
export const startLogin = ({email, password}) => dispatch =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        axios.post(`${USERS_API_BASE_URL}/login`, {
            email,
            password,
        }, {
            withCredentials: true,
        }).then(res => {
            const {token, user} = res.data
            dispatch(setAuth({token, user}))
            resolve(res.data.token)
        }).catch(error =>
            reject(error.response ? error.response.data.message : "Check Your Connection. Please try again later")
        ))
```

**Is API sending Cookie?**
Yes, it is. I have used it in Postman and working as expected. When login using Postman, I can go to authentication protected routes. Here is the function which is triggered on Backend for login

```js
const generateToken = (user, res) => {
    const token = jsonWebToken.sign(
        {id: user.id},
        process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        {
            expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRY
        }
    );
    res
        .status(200)
        .cookie("token", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_EXPIRY * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        })
        .json({
            status: "Success",
            token,
            user
        })
}
```

**Is Login function in React working fine**
Yes, it works. Only when I don't use `{withCredentials: true}`. Otherwise It gives me the error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/login. (Reason: header ‘content-type’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response
```

**Have you implemented CORS?**
Yes, here is the code

```js
// Creating the express app
const app = express()

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}))

app.use(cookieParser())
```

*It gives me the same error if I change the position of cookieParser and cors. Also, if I don't place options in cors(), I get the same error and don't receive any cookie!*

**I think that the problem is with axios request but none of the other solutions on the stackoverflow has worked**

Comment: did you try running the site in chrome? the dev tools over there usually give more feedback about what the problem could be. Cors error usually comes even when there is something else wrong with your setup

Comment: In chrome this error is being shown`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Comment: I have set cookies manually using js-cookie package. But the problem is that it is not be httpOnly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the proxy property in your React package.json? If not try adding the following line:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```